# Identify All non-whitelisted Characters in String (pl/sql)

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I've been given a list of *acceptable* characters, and if a string contains any characters that are not in this whitelist, I need the query to identify them. This can be done via a SELECT query from DUAL, or via an anonymous block in pl/sql.

Is there a way that I can return a string that contains *non whitelisted* characters in an input string without looping?

For my requirements, the whitelist characters are:

- All numbers
- All letters, upper and lower case
- Parentheses
- Curly braces
- Square brackets
- Dashes and underscores
- Plus symbols and equals symbols
- Commas
- Forward slashes (/) and pipes

I can do something like:

```
declare
   myInputString varchar2(256);
   myDirtyCharacters varchar2(256);
begin
   myInputString := '(This is a 123 test@email.com!)';

   myDirtyCharacters := regexp_replace(myInputString,'someRegex');

   dbms_output.put_line('Identified dirty characters: ' || myDirtyCharacters);
end;
```

I would then expect that the `myDirtyCharacters` string would contain a all non-whitelisted characters. In my case, it would be "@!", because the at-symbol and the exclamation point are the only non-whitelisted characters.

Use of the `regexp_replace` function is not a requirement. Any non-looping method could be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (relatively) simple option (from my point of view) is a combination of nested

- `TRANSLATE` function which will remove all whitelisted characters except letters and digits,
- `REGEXP_REPLACE` which removes alphanumerics from what's left,
- `TRIM` which removes unnecessary space characters

Something like this

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '(This (is) a {123 minus - te_st@email.com! 1+1=2/2+2=4/4)' from dual)
  3  select trim(regexp_replace(translate(col, 'a(){}[]-_+=,/|', 'a'), '[[:alnum:]]', '')) result
  4  from test;

RES
---
@.!

SQL>
```